# Vb.net to C# conversion Error cs0103

Tags: c#, vb.net

[image: VB.net Code]

[image: C# Code]

I have made a conversion from VB to C# with telerik online converter. And there is an error as indicated in the second picture. What are the ways that i can solve them?

There is a Name variable in Ship.cs class. But im just think the conversion of syntax is faulty.

My project requires me to fix the codes so that it works exactly like before the conversion. I do not understand the syntax used in VB.

Comment: Looks like an enum indexer property, where the indexer part wasn't converted.

Comment: As Handoko says, please refrain from creating new accounts for each question. Use the login button instead and keep one account.

Answer (score 1):

That is a VB "parameterized property" - there is no direct C# equivalent.
The closest equivalent in C# is to make it a regular method (which is called the same if the original parameterized property only has a 'get'):

```
public Ship GetShip(ShipName name)
{
    if (name == ShipName.None)
        return null;
    else
        return _Ships[name];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should convert it to an accessor:

```
public Ship this[ShipName name]
{
    get 
    { 
        if(name == ShipName.None)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return _Ships[name]; 
    }
}
```

Comment: The original VB method is not an indexer, but a parameterized property - the closest thing in C# is a plain method.